# personalizar excepcion - gestion de excepciones VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

Estoy realizando una aplicación que carga un archivo excel al servidor a través de un `input fileupload`, cuando se sube el archivo se insertan los campos del archivo excel a una BD.

Cuando hay campos que ya han sido cargados (duplicados) no inserta ningun registro de excel (ni duplicados, ni no duplicados), ahora bien cuando hay registros duplicados manda un mensaje en ingles.

¿Se puede traducir?, tambien envia que id's estan duplicados. ¿Cómo los puedo obtener para armar un mensaje mas personalizado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
Public Class Cargador
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim mifichero As HttpPostedFile
    Dim nombreArchivoUsuario As String
    Dim sSheetName As String

    Protected Sub btnAdjuntar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdjuntar.Click

Try
            If (subirArchivos.HasFile) Then
                'Sube el archivo seleccionado a la carpeta adjuntos del servidor
                subirArchivos.SaveAs(MapPath("./adjuntos/" + subirArchivos.FileName))
                mifichero = subirArchivos.PostedFile
                'Obtiene el nombre del archivo que se ha subido
                nombreArchivoUsuario = mifichero.FileName
                lbmostrardv.visible = True
                lbadjuntardv.visible = False
                lbadjuntar.Text = ""
                lbmostrar.Text = nombreArchivoUsuario
                lbmostrare.Text = ""

                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                Dim cn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("reportes").ConnectionString)
                Dim sql1 As SqlClient.SqlCommand
                Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
                cn.Open()
                sql1 = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select nombreCargador from CHIP where nombreCargador='" & nombreArchivoUsuario & "'", cn)
                dr = sql1.ExecuteReader()
                ''------------ Verifica que el archivo no se haya cargado ----------------------------
                If dr.HasRows Then
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alert", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('El archivo " & nombreArchivoUsuario & " ya fue cargado')</script>")
                Else

                    Dim cadconex As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                                        "Data Source=C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\01\adjuntos\" & nombreArchivoUsuario & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"""

                    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
                    conn = New OleDbConnection(cadconex)
                    conn.Open()

                    ''OBTENEMOS NOMBRE DE LA PRIMER HOJA
                    Dim dtExcelSchema As DataTable
                    dtExcelSchema = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
                    Dim SheetName As String = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()

                    ''SELECCIONAMOS TODO LO QUE CONTENGA LA PRIMER HOJA
                    Dim comand As OleDbCommand
                    comand = New OleDbCommand("select * from [Hoja1$]", conn)
                    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
                    adapter.SelectCommand = comand
                    Dim ds As DataSet
                    ds = New DataSet
                    adapter.Fill(ds)
                    conn.Close()

                    ''INSERTAMOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS LO OBTENIDO DEL EXCEL
                    Dim conectsql As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("reportes").ConnectionString)
                    conectsql.Open()
                    Dim importar As SqlBulkCopy

                    importar = New SqlBulkCopy(conectsql)
                    importar.DestinationTableName = "CHIP"
                    importar.WriteToServer(ds.Tables(0))
                    lbimportar.Text = "Se adjuntaron e insertaron correctamente los datos del archivo seleccionado"
                    conectsql.Close()



                    '------------ Bandera de control para que no se carguen archivos de nueva cuenta ----------------------------
                    Dim cn2 As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("reportes").ConnectionString)
                    Dim sql2 As SqlClient.SqlCommand
                    cn2.Open()
                    sql2 = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("update dbo.CHIP set nombreCargador='" + nombreArchivoUsuario + "' WHERE nombreCargador is null ", cn2)
                    sql2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    cn2.Close()
                End If
                dr.Close()
                cn.Close()
                'Catch ex As Exception
                'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<div id='mensaje'>" & ex.Message & "</div>")
                'End Try

                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Else
                lbmostrardv.visible = False
                lbadjuntardv.visible = True
                lbadjuntar.Text = "Error al cargar el archivo. Asegurese de que sea un archivo válido"
                lbmostrar.Text = ""
                lbmostrare.Text = ""
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<div id='mensaje'>" & ex.Message & "</div>")
            lbmostrar.Text = ex.ToString()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías colocar las siguientes instrucciones:

```
Catch ex As Exception
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("es-MX")
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("es-MX")

    lbmostrar.Text = ex.Message.ToString()
End Try
```

Debes tener en cuenta que debes tener instalado el paquete de idiomas de .NET Framework para que te muestre en el idioma necesario.

Answer (score 1):

el ex.ToString() te va a devolver toda la excepcion como tal, información que el usuario no necesita, eso te sirve a ti, pero no al usuario.

Entonces yo prefiero hacer esto.

```
Throw New Exception("Aqui tu texto personalizado : " + ex.Message)
```

el ex.Message le va a mostrar al usuario que fallo, que en este caso seria "cannot insert duplicate etc"

El tema del idioma depende del CurrentUICulture

Comment: y hay alguna intruccion para modificar el CurrentUICulture?

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo(es - ES)

Comment: le coloque la intruccion pero no cambia el texto de ingles a español, estas son las instrucciones que coloque::::::::             Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("es-MX")
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("es-MX")